# Estar exibindo os dados no front-end com node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou com um problema onde basicamente ao inserir os dados de duas tabelas do mysql no front-end não estou conseguindo, creio que eu esteja informando do modo errado.

```
    // Exibir post
    app.get('/cad', function(req, res){
      Aluno.findAll({order: [['id', 'DESC']]}).then(function(alunos){
          res.render('formulario', {alunos: alunos})
      })
  })
    app.get('/cad', function(req, res){
        Post.findAll({order: [['id', 'DESC']]}).then(function(posts){
            res.render('formulario', {posts: posts})
        })
    })
```

tentei dessa forma e mais algumas, desse modo como mostrado acima, o envio dos dados prevalece quem vem primeiro, no caso, eu queria estar enviando os dois ao mesmo tempo, para que eu possa estar exibindo as informações do banco de dados no front-end.
Realizar esse processo seria possivel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível conseguir o resultado esperado utilizando o seguinte padrão.

Pelo que entendi, você quer exibir o resultado de duas tabelas em uma mesma página web.

Utilizando o seu código como exemplo, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
app.get('/cad', function (req, res) {
    Aluno.findAll({ order: [['id', 'DESC']] }).then(function (alunos) {
        const alunosdata = alunos
        Post.findAll({ order: [['id', 'DESC']] }).then(function (posts) {
            res.render('formulario', { posts: posts, alunos: alunosdata })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Apenas uma duvida, eu posso estar incluindo mais tabelas para serem exibidas dessa forma?

Comment: Sim, basta adicionar ao `json` na função render.